# Copy a line of text from Illustrator artboard into save as dialog window

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, save, mac

A small issue but a persistent one: Since the early days of Illustrator I've been unable to copy a line of text from the artboard directly into the 'save as' dialog box when at the point of saving my work. Reason being the filename is always present in the documents I create for my clients and it seems unwieldy to type it out twice.

*(nb I can work around it (but it's cumbersome)—and that is to copy>paste>copy again the text using the find and replace window)*

[image: copy paste into save as]

Comment: What operating system are you using, and what version of Illustrator? I can't replicate the issue using Windows 10 and Illustrator CC 2017. Copying text from the artboard and pasting into the file name works as expected.

Comment: I'm on Illustrator CC  (21.1.0) for the Mac.

Comment: version 21.1.0 is CC 2017. Perhaps this is something you can take up on Adobe's help forums - it sounds like a bug in the Mac version. Also there's a new version of Illustrator out, worth a try maybe?

Comment: Are you copying the text object, or are you copying by highlighting the text with the text tool?

Comment: I've tried copying using both methods Bruce; I suspect the manner in which the text is stored on the clipboard is incompatible with what the Mac OS (in this case Yosemite) is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot I'd assume you're on a Mac.

I can reproduce the problem on my CS6 installation. It seems to be a buggy implementation of the text copy procedure. If I select a line of text and copy it, I can't paste it in the Save dialog.

If after copying, I deselect the text by just clicking on it (getting the blinking cursor back), the text can be pasted.

Comment: Following your procedure isn't working for me alas. How are your preferences set for file handling?

Comment: Same as yours, but it shouldn't matter. They only specify what happens to the Clipboard after AI quits.

Comment: It also works for me if i click anywhere else in the document, before opening the Save dialogue.

Comment: Not happening for me that either. Just tried it on another mac here with  CS3 and a different OS (10.6.8) – same result :-/

Comment: One last try: I only have the problem when I use keyboard shortcuts. When I use the mouse to copy/save/paste, all works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your persistence @AAGD, it doesn't seem to matter whether k'board shortcuts are used or the mouse driven menus. I've looked on the adobe forums and it seems to be an unresolved item. One or two forum threads seem to peter out nothing there. I guess it doesn't rank highly enough for something to be done about it.